# The 2013 survey results blog post has a very low-res image

Tags: bug, survey, blog, survey-2013

The image containing the results on https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/19/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/ is broken, its size is 137px by 1024px.

Comment: I also think they messed up on the title...

Comment: @George Oh, right. That explains why I first posted my question here as 'The 2014 survey results' :p

Comment: Also, Alison Sperling’s profile photo is vertically squashed (on Mobile Safari at least). Compare her photo on the blog post with the one on her profile page (https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/alison/).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ztPXx.jpg) is the full-res image BTW.

Comment: Subscribe to our all-new premium blog for high-resolution images!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm also available on Comcast Premium Tech Package!

Comment: Why **on earth** is that image a jpg anyway? Is 2013 _that far_ in the past?

Comment: No svg designers in the house apparently.

Comment: This is why we need net neutrality.

Comment: [Here's an archive of what the page looked like in June](https://web.archive.org/web/20170620181316/https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/19/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/). Note that this is, in fact, the "2014 Stack Overflow User Survey Results" blog post, not 2013. It was just using a portion of the image from 2013 as a background. the fact that the formatting is messed up makes it appear that it's the blog post for 2013, due to exposing all of the image being used.